# Parametros de tipo clase

Tags: java, poo

Tengo una clase con sus Get y Set

```
public class Bodega{
    
    private Estanteria estanteria1;
}
```

Y tengo la Estanteria con sus respepctivos Get y Set

```
public class Estanteria{
    private Producto producto;
    private int stock;
    private String codigo;
}
```

Tengo uns métodos llamados

```
public void configurarBodega(String codigoEstanteria1) {
        Estanteria estanteria1 = new Estanteria();
        estanteria.setCodigo(codigoEstanteria1);
    }
public void mostrarConfiguracion(){
   System.out.println(estanteria1.getCodigo());
}
```

Tengo un main así

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bodega maquina=new Bodega();
        maquina.configurarBodega("A1");
        maquina.mostrarConfiguracion();

    }
```

Quiero mostrar el código que acabé de configurar en la estantería, pero me sale un valor Null, como si nunca hubiera guardado el valor con el método configurarBodega()

Los métodos mostrarConfiguracion() y configurarBodega(String codigoEstanteria1) están en la clase Bodega

Comment: Hola, en que clase se encuentra el método ``configurarBodega``,  tampoco estas mostrando la clase ``Producto`` , entiendo que estas en POO en el tema de agregación y composición, no te vendría mal revisar el siguiente tutorial en [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oU5LdrH0Uk4)

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero ten cuidado con la tilde de la clase Estanteria.

Prueba a modificar el valor del código con un setCodigo(codigoEstanteria) tal y como te muestro en el codigo:

```
public void configurarBodega(String codigoEstanteria1) {
        Estanteria estanteria1 = new Estanteria();
        estanteria.setCodigo(codigoEstanteria1);
    }
```

Una vez llames al metodo solo tienes que meter por parametro el codigo nuevo para la estanteria:

```
configurarBodega("3453454E");
```

Si no te sirve no dudes en decirlo y explicarme más claramente desde donde estás creando el método y como lo quieres usar.

Comment: No me ha funcionado

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que estás creando una variable local `estanteria1` en lugar de estar modificando la variable de la clase `estanteria1`. Modifica el método `configurarBodega` de la siguiente manera y debe funcionarte:

```
 public void configurarBodega(String codigoEstanteria) {
        estanteria1 = new Estanteria();
        estanteria1.setCodigo(codigoEstanteria);
    }
```

Te dejo un ejemplo de tu código funcionando que puedes ejecutar online https://onlinegdb.com/UTgQNiYEB

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tu variable:

`Estanteria estanteria1` solo vive en la funcion: `configurarBodega()`, es decir, una vez que ese metodo es invocado, se destruyen todas las variables que vivieron dentro.
Lo que debes hacer es referenciar al atributo que existe en la Bodega.

Me refiero a que: en vez de declarar una nueva estantería con:

`Estanteria estanteria = new Estanteria();`

pruebes con
`this.estanteria1 = new Estanteria();`

Comment: Huy, muchas gracias, si me funciona. Me estaba confudiendo mucho con el tema pero ya me sacaste de la duda